# How do I make sure the second dropdown only gets its options from a JQuery API call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have three ASP.NET-Generated drop downs:

```
#FacilityID
#ShiftID
#LineID
```

When the user switches the choice in `#FacilityID`, i need to make a call out to my API and get the new options available for `#ShiftID` and `#LineID`.

Right now, I use the following code to do so:

```
$(function() {
            $("#DefaultFacilityId").change(function() {
                var val = $(this).val();
                var subTypes = "";
                $("#DefaultShiftId").children('option:not(:first)').remove();
                $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetFacilityShifts")",
                    { id: val },
                    function(data) {
                        $.each(data,
                            function(index, item) {
                                subTypes += "<option value='" + item.Id + "'>" + item.ShiftCode + "</option>"
                            });
                        $("#DefaultShiftId").append(subTypes);
                    });

                $("#DefaultLineId").children('option:not(:first)').remove();
                $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetFacilityLines")",
                    { id: val },
                    function(data2) {
                        $.each(data2,
                            function(index, item) {
                                subTypes += "<option value='" + item.Id + "'>" + item.LineName + "</option>"
                            });
                        $("#DefaultLineId").append(subTypes);
                    });
            });
        });
```

We use this exact code on other pages, but usually just one at a time (IE, changing the `#FacilityID` drop down changes the values in `#ShiftID`). Seeing as this is a special case of that exact function, I thought I'd reuse the code as much as I could.

However, I'm running into a result where `#ShiftID` completes normally, but `#LineID` picks up the results for `#ShiftID` AND its own results.

**How do I stop the `#LineID` Drop Down from getting the `#ShiftID` results, and why is this happening?**

Comment: Please include sample data or something so that we can see what your code is doing. Right now we have to guess. One thing: `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. I would suggest emptying just before you fill them, so `$('#LineId').children('option:not(:first)').remove().append(subtypes)`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Can you provide an answer for this comment? Your fix worked perfectly, and I'd like you to get credit for it.

Comment: Frankly, this kind of question gets asked all the time here. It could be closed as a duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](//stackoverflow.com/q/23667086) for instance, since it's basically because you're thinking synchronously. I'd just delete the question. I'm good without the rep :).